# Rails-API not finding superagent request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rails-api, superagent

I'm setting up a Rails-API backend with a React front end, and I'm having some issues sending the requests properly.

Here is the WebApi module inthrough which a user logs in.

```
import request from 'superagent';
import ApiEndpoints from '../constants/ApiEndpoints.jsx';
import AppDispatcher from '../dispatcher/AppDispatcher.jsx';
import SessionConstants from '../constants/SessionConstants.jsx';

function sign_in(params) {
    request
    .post(ApiEndpoints.SIGN_IN) /* http://api.localhost:3000/users/sign_in */
    .send(params)
    .set('Accept', 'vnd.marketplace.v1')
    .set('Content-type', 'application/json')
    .end( (error, response) => {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
            action: SessionConstants.RECEIVE_LOGIN,
            response: response,
            error: error
        });
    });
}

export default { sign_in };
```

Here's the Rails routes I'm using:

```
class ApiConstraints
  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version]
    @default = options[:default]
  end

  def matches?(req)
    debugger
    @default || req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.marketplace.v#{@version}")
  end
end

MarketPlaceApi::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: "/"  do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      devise_for :users
      resources :users, :only => [:show, :create, :update, :destroy]
    end
  end
end
```

The the users/sign_in post route exists in my rake routes:

```
                      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_api_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       api/v1/sessions#new {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
            api_user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       api/v1/sessions#create {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
    destroy_api_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      api/v1/sessions#destroy {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
           api_user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      api/v1/passwords#create {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
       new_api_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  api/v1/passwords#new {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
      edit_api_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) api/v1/passwords#edit {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                             PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      api/v1/passwords#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                             PUT    /users/password(.:format)      api/v1/passwords#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
cancel_api_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        api/v1/registrations#cancel {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
       api_user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               api/v1/registrations#create {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
   new_api_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       api/v1/registrations#new {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
  edit_api_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          api/v1/registrations#edit {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                             PATCH  /users(.:format)               api/v1/registrations#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                             PUT    /users(.:format)               api/v1/registrations#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                             DELETE /users(.:format)               api/v1/registrations#destroy {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                   api_users POST   /users(.:format)               api/v1/users#create {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                    api_user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           api/v1/users#show {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                             PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)           api/v1/users#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           api/v1/users#update {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
                             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           api/v1/users#destroy {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api"}
```

But the request doesn't seem to go through.  I get this error message in my Rails server log, telling me the route was not found.

My question is what did I mess up either on the front or back end?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Rails app log?